# How to make a high-poly monopoly car piece

Tags: modeling, mesh

I'm fairly new to Blender, and I am having some troubles making the iconic car piece from Monopoly:[image]

The part I am having troubles with is the rear of the piece, which can be observed on the left here:[image]

Note how the rear has a sharp edge going down the middle, with the sides being curved. Also, there is the hump near the top as well. If anyone has any ideas on how to model that shape, that would be greatly appreciated! I have inserted the low-poly version that I currently have.

[image]

Edit: I finally made it! Thank you to moonboots for your help. I have inserted the "final" result below. Art is truly never done...

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the solution depends on your current topology, so you could share your file if you want us to give a try.

If I had to do the back of the car from scratch I would begin with a 8th of a subdivided cube that I would stretch and mirror:

[image]

Then I would cut the shape of the outgrowth with the knife tool:

[image]

Extrude it:

[image]

Move the vertices:

[image]

Then retopologize:

[image]

For the rear, you can create a new edge loop then again, extrude:

[image]

[image]

So from your current topology:

[image]

I would simplify like that, then follow the same techniques:

[image]

According to [this article](https://thenewswheel.com/origin-model-inspiration-monopoly-race-car-piece/), the original car could have been inspired by *an old Kurtis Kraft Midget Racer, while others surmise it could be a 1934 Mercedes Grand Prix W25, a Maserati 8CTF, or an Alfa Romero 158*.

In my opinion it's a mix but the Mercedes is pretty close:

[image]

The Alpha Romeo:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for responding! The link is here: [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=M9loJpxr" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/M9loJpxr/) Also, how would you make the rear pointy as seen in the second picture of my original post? And how would I ensure a subsurf modifier wouldn't have any harsh edges (because I wanna make it high poly)?

Comment: I've edited my answer, I hope it helps. If you give it a Subdivision Surface, keep it as low-poly as possible, just add some edge loops where the angles need to be sharp

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much!!

Comment: I have inserted my final render to my original question. I could play with lighting and angles a bit, but I'm really grateful for your insight!